# Как сделать бесконечную карусель?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, карусель

Такой вопрос часто задают, но ответа я не нашёл. Сделать карусель легко, но бесконечную и без использования современных css-свойст сложно. Бесконечная карусель базируеться на добавление или дублирование элементов. Для прокрутки используют transition либо left. Но основная проблема заключаеться в потере плавности при добавления/удаление элементов для бесконечной прокрутки. Что можете посоветовать для решение такой проблемы ?

```js
  let left = document.getElementById("arrowLeft");
        let right = document.getElementById("arrowRight");
        let carusel = document.getElementById("carusel");

        left.addEventListener("click", clickLeft);
        right.addEventListener("click", clickRight);

        const caruselElem = 3;
        const width = 100 / caruselElem;
        const item = carusel.children.length - caruselElem;
        let current = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < carusel.childElementCount; i++) {
            carusel.children[i].style.minWidth = width + "%";
        }

        function clickLeft() {
            current -= 1;
            if (current < 0) {
                current = item;
            }
            carusel.style.transform = `translateX(-${width * current}%)`;
        }
        function clickRight() {
            current += 1;
            if (current > item) {
                current = 0;
            }
            carusel.style.transform = `translateX(-${width * current}%)`;
        }
```

```css
 * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            main {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                background: #0e38b1;
            }
            nav {
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            div {
                display: flex;
                transition: 0.5s;
            }
            img {
                object-fit: cover;
                aspect-ratio: 16/9;
            }
            i {
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 50px;
                color: #ffffff;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
```

```html
<body>
        <main>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left" id="arrowLeft"><</i>
            <nav>
                <div id="carusel">
                    <img
                        src="https://static-cse.canva.com/blob/846923/photo1502082553048f009c37129b9e1583341920812.jpeg"
                    />
                    <img
                        src="https://white-rainbow.ru/upload/resize_cache/iblock/b26/7sf66d03tagu4tqpxywzr9e18325c05v/600_400_1/BSA_3747_Pano_copy.750.jpg"
                    />
                    <img
                        src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/be/39/7c/be397c91b8026b17f5f8a6ed98e23e9e.jpg"
                    />
                    <img
                        src="https://s0.rbk.ru/v6_top_pics/media/img/6/76/756602873502766.jpg"
                    />
                    <img
                        src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/be/39/7c/be397c91b8026b17f5f8a6ed98e23e9e.jpg"
                    />
                    <img
                        src="https://pibig.info/uploads/posts/2021-06/1623997495_14-pibig_info-p-priroda-solntse-priroda-krasivo-foto-16.jpg"
                    />
                </div>
            </nav>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" id="arrowRight">></i>
        </main>
    </body>
```

> Конечно можно использовать swiper - но для такой мелочи странно
> использовать целую библиотеку.

Comment: Я бы предпочел делать цикличный массив, а карусель пусть сгенерирует картинки из этого массива как обычно.

Comment: последний слайд поворачиваете на 90 градусов и перемещаете в начало, после перемещения отменяете поворот. ну это так... для ассортимента :3

Answer (score 0):

### Описание

Я бы предпочел немного хитрый подход. Я бы создал цикличный список, который бы вернул мне элемент под любым индексом, даже отрицательным и бы сгенерировал так чтобы показалось это как бесконечный карусель.

### Решение

Я не напишу код полностью, вместо этого дам вам ключевые моменты.

##### Структура

Вот так, собственно, выглядит структура этого списка.

```js
/**
 * @template T
 */
class LoopedList {
    /** @type {T[]} */ #items = [];
    get period() {
        return this.#items.length;
    }
    /**
     * @param {number} index 
     * @returns {T}
     */
    get(index) {
        index %= this.period;
        if (index < 0) index += this.period;
        return this.#items[index];
    }
    /**
     * @param {number} index 
     * @param {T} value
     */
    set(index, value) {
        index %= this.period;
        if (index < 0) index += this.period;
        this.#items[index] = value;
    }
    /**
     * @param {T} value 
     */
    add(value) {
        this.#items.push(value);
    }
    /**
     * @param {T} value 
     */
    delete(value) {
        const index = this.#items.indexOf(value);
        if (index > 0) {
            this.#items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Методы `add` и `delete` будут работать напямую с массивом, а `get` и `set` создадут "эффект бесконечности".

##### Использование

И вот таким простым способом его можно использовать

```js
/** @type {LoopedList<string>} */ const listSources = new LoopedList();
listSources.add(`ссылка 1`);
listSources.add(`ссылка 2`);
listSources.add(`ссылка 3`);

let index = 0;
buttonPrevious.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
    img.src = listSources.get(--index);
});
buttonNext.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
    img.src = listSources.get(++index);
});
```

Вам надо будет немного поработать над анимациями, рендерингом и будеть вам решение.

### Плавность и прокрутка

Как, собственно, создать плавный переход?
У вас будут 2 кнопки - для прокрутки назад и вперед. Решение симетричное поэтому, решим для одного.
Как только пользователь жмет кнопку "Вперед" (к примеру) вы создаете элемент `<img>` справа от текущего, задаете `src` следующую ссылку, потом оба элемента плавно идут влево и как только предыдущий `<img>` уходит за завесы, вы удаляйте его.
Так у вас всегда будет всего несколько `<img>`, в центре будет текущая картинка и все будет происходить плавно, без сбоев.